# Run function if specific word is found in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, click, contains

I am looking for a way to run a function if my array contains the word 'AGE'. I am rather terrible at coding but have pieced together this code:

HTML:

```
<div class="finish" >?</div>
```

Script:

```
var co = ["AGE"]

    $(document).ready(function(){
       $(".finish").click(function(){ 
            if (co.contains("AGE")) {
                alert($.unique(co));
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

What could be missing? I am sure it should be very easy, but I am not getting anywhere.

Comment: You'll get a lot more views if you actually use the right tags..

Comment: Ah, what tags would you use? Then I will try to change them.

Comment: how about, "javascript" and "jquery", like the ones i already added for you.

Comment: Thank you a lot for adding them for me, it seems it helped a lot. I will think more carefully which I add next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up with this version:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var co = ["AGE"];

    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".finish").click(function(){ 
        if ($.inArray("AGE", co) >= 0) {
          alert($.unique(co));
          return false;
        }
      });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="finish" >?</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the link to the documentation of that helper method from jQuery:
[jQuery.inArray()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/).

Comment: with the exception of the unnecessary `>`, this is the exact same answer as the other one...

Comment: That might happen, if the solution is the same. Alas the > is not unnecessary, as the method either returns -1 or an index which is non-negative and not 0 in general.

Comment: I'm sorry, I guess you're right. It looks like the other guy is copying you now, so switching my votes..

Comment: Yeah @mvw is correct with the >= I missed the part in the documentation that said it would return the index.

Comment: Is there a way to delete my answer?

Comment: @anthony, yes, the delete button next to the edit button.

Comment: @Adelphia thanks. I'm on mobile at the moment and there is no delete button, but I'll delete it once I get on my laptop.